# What's different about French Cursive from all the other Calligraphical Fonts?

Tags: fonts, packages

I was trying out some of the different calligraphy fonts that I could find on:

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html

But noticed something odd about French Cursive, which is that there is no command for using it in a section, instead you load it as the default font for "\normalfont" i.e.:

```
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I was wondering why that is and if I wanted to use this font for a section only, how I would do it. All the other fonts seem to work differently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: \documentclass{article}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\fontfamily{frc}\selectfont\Large\bfseries test
\end{document}
```

Comment: This definitely worked. How did you know to use frc in fontfamily?

Comment: @user73236 for example: texdoc.net  http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/frcursive/frcursive.pdf#page=2

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{frcursive}

\begin{document}

Normal text here...
{\cursive My cursive text here...}
Normal text here again...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! That is a much better approach than the other answer.  Note that you can also use `\textcursive{....}`.